# Keep trying a print command LP until successful

Tags: ssh, command, rm, exit-status, lp

I wish to keep sending the printer print command until the print succeeds. If it succeeds printing then it should delete the file.

Below is my script.

```
until ssh root@45.76.162.227 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series $FILE'
do
  echo "Deleting $FILE"
  rm $FILE; 
done
```

The issue is that it deletes the file `rm $FILE;` even if the print command `lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series $FILE` fails.

Below is a sample failing print command.

```
ssh root@remotehost 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /home/system/test8.pdf'

lp: Transport endpoint is not connected

[system@live send4print]$ echo $?
1
```

Can you please suggest how can I meet my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not understanding how iteration works.

Your script says:

```
Until successful:
  print stuff, and delete files
```

```
until ssh root@45.76.162.227 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series $FILE'
do
  echo "trying again"
done

echo "Deleting $FILE"
rm $FILE;
```

There seems to be some other problems:

- FILE is in capitals (latent bug: capital letters are reserved and should not be used).
- Quoting problem `$FILE` will not be expanded.
- It would be a good idea to rate throttle it, put a `sleep` in there.